# Zoneminder missing api folder

Tags: ubuntu, zoneminder

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed and I am running Zoneminder 1.28.1.

The github repository for Zoneminder has an api directory under the web directory.  However, the repository for Ubuntu 12.04 does not install this folder when upgrading Zoneminder.

I have added the iconner (ppa:iconnor/zoneminder-master) repo to Ubuntu and have done a apt-get update and apt-get upgrade but it says everything is up to date.

The api directory in github says it uses CMake to do some things on the files in the directory. Is there any way to add this folder without having to checkout the source from github and doing a clean make install?

I have a lot of configurations setup and I don't want to lose them.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. I am not the only one having this issue.  I followed this guide and it worked correctly...

[Guide to adding API to Zoneminder](http://iain.rauch.co.uk/blog/2014-12/zoneminder-1-28-api/)